# Как массово обновить значения в таблице в соответствии с индексом id в массиве?

Tags: mysql

У меня есть таблица в БД. С полями `id`, `pos`. А также есть массив с идентификаторами:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 1858 
    [1] => 1863 
    [2] => 1725 
    [3] => 1595 
    [4] => 1834 
    [5] => 1835 
    [6] => 1859 
    // ... и т.д.
)
```

Я хочу сделать `update` в таблице таким образом, чтобы в колонке `pos` было значение, равное индексу в массиве + 1, то есть для 1858 `pos` был равен 1, для 1863 - 2, для 1725 - 3 и т.д.

Это можно как-то в один запрос сделать ёмко? Или тут только два пути: 1) в цикле делать `update` с `where` 2) в запросе городить гигантский `switch/case` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [FIELD](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php):

```
update table
   set pos=field(id,'1858','1863',...)
```

**UPD** Или, по предложению @Akina:

```
update table
   set pos=find_in_set(id,'1858,1863,...')
```

Comment: FIELD() сложноват для запроса с параметром... а вот `set pos=FIND_IN_SET(id,'1858,1863,...')` прекрасно параметризуется. Да и слить массив в один литерал куда как проще.

Comment: @Akina `слить массив в один литерал куда как проще.` - чем?  ..... `FIELD() сложноват для запроса с параметром` - для моей задачи параметры не нужны, т.к. идентификаторы приходят не от пользователя...но можете добавить еще ответ

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я соглашусь с Akina массив немного проще собрать implode в строку через запятую, чем в строку с элементами в кавычках через запятую

Comment: @Mike аа, я не сразу заметил разницу просто